# How to remove square brackets of number in json array using json data extractor

Tags: json, jmeter-5.0

My json response is

```json
{
  "message": "Lead created successfully",
  "id": "[667]",
  "input_data": null,
  "result": [],
  "statusCode": 200
}
```

and I need only 667 to pass to an url as path param. I'm using $.id[0] using json data extractor , but getting response as [667] instead of 667, please help.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, with `json data extractor` there is no way to help you to do that, Use Regular Expression instead.

[image]

Result

[image]

Comment: thank you @lucasnguyen17 for answering, but it works for me only after removing space after the colon in regex